# How to force yesod/warp to close open file handles before handling next request?

Tags: haskell, file-io, concurrency, yesod, haskell-warp

I've written a small server which accepts registrations as POST requests and persists them by appending them to a file. As soon as I put this server under load (I use Apache JMeter with 50 concurrent threads and a repeat count of 10, and the post consists of one field with ~7k of text data), I get lots of "resource busy, file is locked" errors:

```
02/Nov/2013:18:07:11 +0100 [Error#yesod-core] registrations.txt: openFile: resource busy (file is locked) @(yesod-core-1.2.4.2:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ./Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:485:5)
```

Here is a stripped-down version of the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, MultiParamTypeClasses, OverloadedStrings, TypeFamilies #-}

import           Yesod
import           Text.Hamlet
import           Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import           Data.Text (Text, pack, unpack)
import           Data.String
import           System.IO (withFile, IOMode(..), hPutStrLn)

data Server = Server

data Registration = Registration
        { text      :: Text
        }
    deriving (Show, Read)

mkYesod "Server" [parseRoutes|
/reg    RegR    POST
|]

instance Yesod Server

instance RenderMessage Server FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

postRegR :: Handler Html
postRegR = do
    result <- runInputPost $ Registration
        <$> ireq textField "text"
    liftIO $ saveRegistration result
    defaultLayout [whamlet|<p>#{show result}|]

saveRegistration :: Registration -> IO ()
saveRegistration r = withFile "registrations.txt" AppendMode (\h -> hPutStrLn h $ "+" ++ show r)

main :: IO ()
main = warp 8080 Server
```

I compiled the code on purpose without `-threaded`, and the OS shows only a single thread running. Nonetheless it looks to me like the requests are not completely serialised, and a new request is already handled before the old one has been written to disk.

Could you tell me how I can avoid the error message and ensure that all requests are handled successfully? Performance is not an issue yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even without `-threaded` the Haskell runtime will have several "green threads" running cooperatively. You need to use [`Control.Concurrent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html) to limit access to the file because you cannot have several threads writing to it at once.

The easiest way is to have an [`MVar ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html) in your `Server` and have each request "take" the unit from the `MVar` before opening the file and then put it back after the file operation has been completed. You can use `bracket` to ensure that the lock is released even if writing the file fails. E.g. something like

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception (bracket_)

type Lock = MVar ()
data Server = Server { fileLock :: Lock }

saveRegistration :: Registration -> Lock -> IO ()
saveRegistration r lock = bracket_ acquire release updateFile where
    acquire = takeMVar lock
    release = putMVar lock ()
    updateFile =
        withFile "registrations.txt" AppendMode (\h -> hPutStrLn h $ "+" ++ show r)
```

Comment: To clarify: it's perfectly OK to write to a `Handle` from several threads - `Handle`s have `MVar`s inside them to prevent weird concurrent behaviour.  What you probably want is not to handle `MVar`s by hand (which can lead to deadlock if a handler throws an exception) but lift the `withFile` outside the individual threads.  The file stays open, but that's probably inevitable (opening it on each request would be slow anyway).

Comment: Fixnum: That's actually a much better way. You should put that as an answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't mark both yours and Fixnum's answers as accepted, because a combination of both solved my problem perfectly: I've used an MVar as you described, and Fixnum's example showed me how to do it. Thank you!!!

Comment: @AxelHanikel: I added a short example which uses `bracket`. Without that any errors that might happen when updating the file would leave the `MVar` empty and the application deadlocked.

Comment: I've tried to use `bracket` as well but your example is a lot more readable than what I did, so I'll remember it not only for the functionality but also as an example for writing code that is easy to read. I'll mark this answer as the accepted answer now because I think it's the most concise recipe for other newbie Haskellers running into the same problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly OK to write to a `Handle` from several threads.  In fact, `Handle`s have `MVar`s inside them to prevent weird concurrent behaviour. What you probably want is not to handle [sic] `MVar`s by hand (which can lead to deadlock if, for instance, a handler throws an exception) but lift the `withFile` call outside the individual handler threads.  The file stays open all the time - opening it on each request would be slow anyway.

I don't know much about Yesod, but I'd recommend something like this (probably doesn't compile):

```
data Server = Server { handle :: Handle }

postRegR :: Handler Html
postRegR = do
    h <- handle `fmap` getYesod
    result <- runInputPost $ Registration
        <$> ireq textField "text"
    liftIO $ saveRegistration h result
    defaultLayout [whamlet|<p>#{show result}|]

saveRegistration :: Handle -> Registration -> IO ()
saveRegistration h r = hPutStrLn h $ "+" ++ show r

main :: IO ()
main = withFile "registrations.txt" AppendMode $ \h -> warp 8080 (Server h) 
-- maybe there's a better way?
```

Aside: if you wanted to file to be written asynchronously you could write to a queue (if it were a log file or something), but in your use case you probably want to let the user know if their registration failed, so I'd recommend staying with this form.

Comment: As a first try I've used your example but left the `withFile` in the `saveRegistration` function and passed it an `MVar`. Then I've surrounded the `hPutStrLn` with a `takeMVar` / `putMVar` and I've had no errors in hundreds of requests! In order to avoid the deadlock you described, I've also tried to put the `putMVar` inside the handler function in `withFile`, but surprisingly that didn't work. Finally I've tried your solution and it is indeed faster. Thank you very much for the detailed example!

Comment: Taking locks *inside* the `withFile` (if I understand you) doesn't work because your error results from trying to *open* an already open file, which is caused by `withFile` itself.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah, of course, now that you say it, it makes perfect sense! I hope you don't mind that I've marked shang's answer as the accepted one: your solution is more efficient but it completely avoids the problem , whereas shang's answer contains an explanation of the unexpected behaviour, and a generic solution to it which might also be applicable to other people's code. Thank you so much, I've learned a lot from both your answers!